# JSON getting data

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jqgrid

I am trying to get the data from the following JSON:

```
{
    "store": "4",
    "latestStatusChange.storeStatus": "OFFLINE",
    "latestStatusChange.transitionTime": "2014 Jul 20 21:40:09",
    "lcp": "S2",
    "number30MinuteOldLocks": "3",
    "numberCurrentLocalLocks": "4",
    "numberErrorDeltas": "5",
    "numberUnsyncedDeltas": "6",
    "rail": "S2-2",
    "heartbeatTime": "2014 Jul 20 20:17:05"
}
```

how do I get the data from the 'latestStatusChange.transitionTime' property?

Comment: I'm assuming you are trying to use dot notation  `jsonobject.latestStatusChange.transitionTime`. This won't work because of the dot, it tries to access `latestStatusChange` as an object and the key of `transitionTime`. Use brackets to access it  `jsonobject['latestStatusChange.transitionTime']`. If you don't have the json in an object yet you will have to do var `jsonobject = JSON.parse(jsonstring);`.

Comment: using the brackets did not work. I get undefined transitionTime.

Comment: This works perfectly fine. Please see [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jayV7/)

Comment: thanks, but I got: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o when using your suggestion.

Comment: I got it working using Adam suggestions. Thanks Adam

Comment: I've added my comment as an answer so you can accept it and close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are trying to use dot notation `jsonobject.latestStatusChange.transitionTime`. This won't work because of the dot, it tries to access `latestStatusChange` as an object and the key of `transitionTime`. Use brackets to access it `jsonobject['latestStatusChange.transitionTime']`. If you don't have the json in an object yet you will have to do var `jsonobject = JSON.parse(jsonstring);`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like :

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://example.com',
    method : "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    success : function($response){
        console.log($response['latestStatusChange.transitionTime']);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Like

```
var text = '{"name":"John Johnson","street":"Oslo West 16","phone":"555 1234567"}'

var obj = JSON.parse(text);
debugger;
alert(obj.name);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ashuslove/HkEuf/2578/)